# Using laravel websockets package in docker environment

Tags: laravel, docker, websocket

### Use case n° 1:

#### steps

- installing the package in the same container of the laravel project
- configuring the pusher settings in `.env` & `boradcasting.php` like so

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=123456789
PUSHER_APP_KEY=AZERTYUIOP
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=QSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
PUSHER_APP_HOST=localhost # or 127.0.0.1
```

```php
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                // 'encrypted' => false,
                'host' => env('PUSHER_APP_HOST'),
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http',
            ],
        ],
```

- Exposing port `6001` in `Dockerfile` of project container.
- using the package by running `php artisan websockets:serve` from within the container.
- testing the package by dispatching `WebSocketsTestEvent` event from a **tinker session**

```php
class WebSocketsTestEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    protected $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('test');
    }
}
```

### Use case n° 2:

#### steps

- installing the package in the same container of the laravel project
- configuring the pusher settings in `.env` like so :

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=123456789
PUSHER_APP_KEY=AZERTYUIOP
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=QSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
PUSHER_APP_HOST=ssms-app # or the @IP of the conatiner
```

- creating a Dockerfile for `websockets` container like so:

```
FROM php:7.3.3-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache \
    wget \
    curl \
    # git \
    shadow \
    build-base \
    autoconf \
    # hiredis \
    libxml2-dev \
    zlib-dev \
    libevent \
    libevent-dev \
    openssl-dev \
    gmp-dev \
    icu-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
        pcntl \
        mbstring \
        pdo \
        pdo_mysql \
        tokenizer \
        xml \
        sockets \
        gmp \
        bcmath \
        intl

        # Libevent
RUN pecl install event

RUN apk update

# Cleanup
# apk del .build-deps && \
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    rm -rf /tmp/*

RUN mkdir -p /var/www

RUN groupmod -g 1000 www-data && \
    usermod -u 1000 www-data

USER www-data

WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 6001

CMD ["php", "artisan", "websockets:serve"]
```

- configuring `docker-compose.yaml` like so:

```
  ssms-app:
    build:
      context: ./docker/app
      args:
        uid: ${UID}
    container_name: ssms-app
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=#${UID}
      - APACHE_RUN_GROUP=#${UID}
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - ${HOST_PORT}:80
      # - 6001:6001
    links:
      - ssms-redis
      - ssms-sockets
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - ssms-app

  ssms-sockets:
    build:
      context: ./docker/websockets
    container_name: ssms-sockets
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 6001:6001
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - ssms-sockets
```

### Observations:

- in both cases i get the same issues:

  - the graph in the dashboard, after visiting `http://localhost:8080/laravel-websockets` is not displayed.

    > Note: this is fixed by setting `'perform_dns_lookup' => true` in `config/websockets.php`.
  - no traces indicating that the event is broadcasted by the package in the dashboard.
  - besides that, when using **event creator** from the dashboard I get **422** status code in the console
  - many developer encountered the same issue when using it with docker environment, but some of the use cases worked for ones but not for others

At last, **Any solutions? I'm stuck for about 3 days**

Comment: Regarding Event Creater, I'm using channel: `home`, event: `App\Events\NewMessage`, and message in JSON: `{   "message": "Hello World"  }` To me here it is working, also I'm using `Channel` instead `PrivateChannel`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am in the same situation and I can't figure out why I am not able to connect to the websocket from anywhere.

Comment: @Flobbo actually i didn't figure it out, but the issue is addressed and no answers till now!.

Comment: also i'm not working in the project from a long time, sorry

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems like this is simply impossible.

Comment: Ohh boy, I've been fighting this for three days already,.. result: none.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your docker setup. For that, I have upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try to edit the .env file to use `host.docker.internal`
like so

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=123456789
PUSHER_APP_KEY=AZERTYUIOP
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=QSDFGHJKLMWXCVBN
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
PUSHER_APP_HOST=host.docker.internal
```

after than run `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 0):

Good day I got a websocket server running on a Docker build by using Laravel Echo image to build my docker and then setting my app and portal(the second application) To authenticate with the socket server and I could send messages vice versa. This is Laravel echo docker image I used to build my docker stack https://github.com/oanhnn/docker-laravel-echo-server

I don't think using the artisan websockets:serve would work as you are running the socket in a container and would need to expose a port for it. Well atleast I could not get it working that way so I did it with laravel echo.